# How to transform ? and : operations in IF and ELSE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery:

```
var $gallery = $('#slideshow'),
    $active = $gallery.find('img:visible'),
    $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $gallery.find('img').first();
```

To be easier to understand, how do I transform the third line into an if/else statement?

Comment: Do you know how an `if` statement is structured?  What have you tried?

Comment: I'm curious what the advantage is over the ternary

Answer (score 1):

Lets start off by saying that the way it is written is just as easy to understand and IMO is the preferred method.  That being said, if you really want to change it to an if else statement here is an example

```
var $gallery = $('#slideshow'),
    $active = $gallery.find('img:visible'),
    $next;
if($active.next().length){
    $next = $active.next();
} else {
    $next = $gallery.find('img').first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if ($active.next().length)
{
  $next = $active.next();
}
else
{
  $next = $gallery.find('img').first();
}
```